# Problems loading Data into UITableView from another Class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently, I have my JSON data retrieval code in side the view controller and everything works fine. As I added more features to my app, I realized I should have a separate class that's job is to make data requests so other viewControllers can request data without having to have repeated code throught each view controller.

After I moved my data request code into a new class, I am having trouble getting my tableView to load data from the class. The data connection is working as I have an NSLog spitting out what is getting requested, but the data isn't populating in my tableView.

New Class Code

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
// so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
// Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
// also serves to clear it
_searchResponseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
[_searchResponseData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"Recieved Data");

}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
// Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now

gameViewController *gameTableClass = [[gameViewController alloc] init];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *Data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_searchResponseData options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", Data);
NSDictionary *parseData = [archiveData objectForKey:@"games"];
gameDataArray  = [parseData objectForKey:@"game"];
gameTableClass.gameSearchArray = gameDataArray;
[gameTableClass.tableView reloadData];
[[[gameTableClass searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// The request has failed for some reason!
// Check the error var
NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

-(void)newConnectionToServer:(NSURLRequest *)searchRequest {
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:searchRequest delegate:self];
}
```

ViewController with TableView

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [gameSearchArray count];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}


NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [gameSearchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tempDictionary valueForKey:@"system_title"];


return cell;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This line, gameViewController *gameTableClass = [[gameViewController alloc] init];, is creating a new instance of gameViewController, not the one you made in the storyboard, so of course, the one you see on screen is not updated. The pattern you want to follow is that which Matias R suggests in his answer.

Comment: @rdelmar I see, I'll look for an example on how to implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is that you're initializing gameViewController from your "service" class. You're calling the init method, can you show us that code? are you initializing the table view there? setting it's delegate and data source? or are you using storyboards?

My recommendation is to not initialize the view controller from a service class.
Your UIViewController should call this class to obtain the data, and then use a delegate pattern to notify the view controller when the data from the server is available.

Let me know if you need an example.

**EDITED WITH SAMPLE CODE:**

In your "New Class Code" class, declare a protocol in the header (.h) file:

```
@protocol SomeClassDelegate
    - (void)didReceiveGameData:(NSArray *)gameData;
@end

@interface NewClassCode : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id<SomeClassDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In your "New Class Code" implementation (.m):

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *Data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_searchResponseData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", Data);
    NSDictionary *parseData = [archiveData objectForKey:@"games"];
    gameDataArray  = [parseData objectForKey:@"game"];
    if (_delegate) {
        [_delegate didReceiveGameData:gameDataArray];
    }
}
```

Then in the UIViewController where you use your "New Class Code" class:

1. Declare the UIViewController to implement the protocol you just defined

   ```
   @interface NewClassCode () <SomeClassDelegate>
   ```
2. Implement the method defined in the interface

   ```
   - (void)didReceiveGameData:(NSArray *)gameData {
       self.gameData = gameData;
       [self.tableView reloadData]
   }
   ```
3. Set your view controller as delegate of the service class (what you call New Class Code):

   ```
   newClassCode.delegate = self;
   ```

This is basically the delegate pattern, you can search on the internet for more details, but this example should get you started. Basically your view controller asks the service class to perform an action and notify it when it's done. You should also do something similar for error cases.
Another nice way of doing it would be with blocks, or using AFNetworking which already is using blocks.

Comment: R Thanks! I originally set everything up in Storyboards. So the table view data source and delegate are the tableview within the gameViewController. If you could provide an example, that would be wonderful. Thanks!